# UI-Router isnt rendering childs correctly with templateurl in Asp.net Mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have states mentioned like this

```
 $stateProvider
        .state('dashboard', {
            url: "/dashboard",
            views: {
                content: { templateUrl: "/dashboard/index" }
            }
        }).state('accounts', {
            url: "/accounts",
            views: {
                'content': { templateUrl: "/accounts/index" }
            }
        })
        .state('accounts.add', {
            url: "/add",
            views: {
                'content': { templateUrl: "/accounts/add" }
            }
        });
```

and the URLS are

```
<a class="list-group-item submenu" ui-sref="accounts">Service Users</a>
<a class="list-group-item submenu" ui-sref="accounts.add">Add User</a>
```

I am using asp.net Mvc so my Controller which serves the templates currently looks like this

```
 public class AccountsController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Accounts/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return Request.IsAjaxRequest() ? (ActionResult)PartialView("_Icons") : View();
    }   

    public ActionResult Add()
    {
        return Request.IsAjaxRequest() ? (ActionResult)PartialView("_Add") : View();
    }
}
```

But whenever I make request to the state `accounts.add` then it always calls the `accounts` state .And renders the `_icons` view which is nothing but a partial view as `_icons.cshtml`. I can see in firebug that url has been called but it never gets rendered . WHY ????

The firebug output is something like this

```
GET http://localhost:2060/accounts/index 200 OK 2ms
GET http://localhost:2060/accounts/add 200 OK 5ms
```

This is what happens when I click `ui-sref="accounts.add"` and ends up rendering the index action . Can someone tell me why is this happening ? It shouldn't be happening . Is there something which I am missing out as convention from ui-router ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QfRVkhapI2MgoChlUdWS?p=preview) showing/explaining the issue.

The point is, that this child state:

```
.state('accounts.add', {
    url: "/add",
    views: {
        'content': { templateUrl: "/accounts/add" }
    }
```

has the same **view** name as its parent: 'content'. This in fact does **not** mean, that they target the same view. No - child is searching for a view in a Parent - with the same name `content`.

The target for the parent state *(`accounts`)* is the Index.html *(in ASP.NET MVC /home/)*:

```
<body>
    <div ui-view="content" ></div>
</body>
```

The target for the child state *(`accounts.add`)* is the `templateUrl: "/dashboard/index"`:

```
<div>
  ... parent content ...
  ... and here is the place holder for child state (with the same name)
  ... "content"
  <div ui-view="content" ></div>
</div>
```

The way how to target the root `ui-view="content"` *(index.html)* is to use absolute naming. In the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QfRVkhapI2MgoChlUdWS?p=preview) I used Insert state for that:

```
 .state('accounts.insert', {
     url: "/insert",
     views: {
         'content@': { templateUrl: "accounts.insert.tpl.html" }
     }
```

Where in the view name `'content@'` the **`@`** i is the way how to target the root. Please check the documentation for more details:

- [View Names - Relative vs. Absolute Names](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names)

Small extract:

```
views: {
    ////////////////////////////////////
    // Relative Targeting             //
    // Targets parent state ui-view's //
    ////////////////////////////////////

    // Relatively targets the 'detail' view in this state's parent state, 'contacts'.
    // <div ui-view='detail'/> within contacts.html
    "detail" : { },            

    // Relatively targets the unnamed view in this state's parent state, 'contacts'.
    // <div ui-view/> within contacts.html
    "" : { }, 

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Absolute Targeting using '@'                      //
    // Targets any view within this state or an ancestor //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // Absolutely targets the 'info' view in this state, 'contacts.detail'.
    // <div ui-view='info'/> within contacts.detail.html
    "info@contacts.detail" : { }

    // Absolutely targets the 'detail' view in the 'contacts' state.
    // <div ui-view='detail'/> within contacts.html
    "detail@contacts" : { }

    // Absolutely targets the unnamed view in parent 'contacts' state.
    // <div ui-view/> within contacts.html
    "@contacts" : { }

    // absolutely targets the 'status' view in root unnamed state.
    // <div ui-view='status'/> within index.html
    "status@" : { }
```

Comment: So in a manner when `/account` renders ... its searching the `content` view inside that outside ui-view which had `content` view name i I have understood correctly . Is tht so ? your idea is working fine . I am just clarifying my understanding .

Comment: You are right: I would put it this way: State defines content of the views defined in its parent... unless more precise (@) naming is used. This way, we can even target views, defined in current state *(e.g. hint@accounts could be defined in one of the *main* accounts views)* But yes, now you understand that clearly ;) Enjoy ui-router ;)