# child state controller not being reached in angular-ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the following setup in my code

```
.config(function config($stateProvider)
    $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url : '/home',
          views : {
            'main' : {
              controller : 'HomeCtrl',
              templateUrl : 'home/home.tpl.html'
            }
          }
        })
      .state('home.details', {
        url : '/details',
        views : {
          " " : {
            template : "<h1>hello</h1>",
            controller : function ($scope, $http, $state) {
              //do some stuff here
              //does not seem to reach code in here
            }
         }
        }
  });
})
.controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $state) {
    //on a button click do $state.go('.details');
});
```

When I do this , the button click on my `HomeCtrl` seems to take me to /home/details but it does not seems to go inside the controller in that particular route at that point. (I checked by putting a break point inside the controller for the details.) Is there something wrong with my setup? I'm trying to do something similar to this [sample app](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/contacts) shown in the `ui-router` webpage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution here would in a `named-view` *(not)* matching. Here is the working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VfM0Cd?p=preview).

We have to place the **named** `ui-view` inside of the parent view *(or use more precise naming, see for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23848621/1679310))*

So, the parent, home template should contain the named `ui-view`, e.g. **nameOtherThanSpace**

```
<div ui-view="nameOtherThanSpace" ></div>
```

And the child defintion must target that view, the complete snippet is:

```
  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      views: {
        'main': {
          controller: 'HomeCtrl',
          template: '<div>' +
            '<h1>hello from parent</h1>' +
            '<hr />' +
            '<div ui-view="nameOtherThanSpace" ></div>' +
            '<div>',
        }
      }
    })
    .state('home.details', {
      url: '/details',
      views: {
        "nameOtherThanSpace": {
          template: "<h2>hello from a child</h3>",
          controller: function($scope, $http, $state) {},
        }
      }
    });
```

How to use more specific view names:

- [View Names - Relative vs. Absolute Names](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names)
- [UI-Router isnt rendering childs correctly with templateurl in Asp.net Mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23847068/)

The working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VfM0Cd?p=preview) using the name **nameOtherThanSpace**, instead of " " (space)

Comment: Thanks, that works. I guess this statement `When a state is activated, its templates are automatically inserted into the ui-view of its parent state's template` in the docs, threw me off. I thought that meant the it didn't need a matching named view.

Comment: Correct, named views must match! good if that helped anyhow. Enjoy `ui-router` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try registering your controller on the app instead of on your $stateProvider. e.g.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $state) {
    //on a button click do $state.go('.details');
});
```

**Update 1:**

You should only need to specify a view if you have multiple views in which case the view probably needs to have a name. But you only have one view for that state so I would just do this.

```
.state('home.details', {
    url : '/details'
    template : "<h1>hello</h1>",
    controller : function ($scope, $http, $state) {
      //do some stuff here
      //does not seem to reach code in here
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, the controller is registered on the module. I just got the chaining wrong. I have edited it now. So it looks like `angular.module(...).config(...).controller(...)`

Comment: @Deepak Updated my answer with another idea